# Running function with std::istream

Tags: c++, istream

I am trying to input a value in my function, which looks like this:

```
int funkcija( std::istream & in ) {
    int value(0);
    in >> value;
    if(not in) throw std::exception();
    if( value%2 == 0 ) {
        return (value/2);
    }
    else return (value*3)+1;
}
```

When I try to run it:

```
int i(0);
std::cout << "Input a number: ";
std::cin >> i;
funkcija(i);
```

I get an error:
..\working.cpp:17:14: error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}' from expression of type 'int'
..\working.cpp:7:5: error: in passing argument 1 of 'int funkcija(std::istream&)'

What does it mean and how to solve it? Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't that call be `i = funkcija(cin);` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to pass the integer you've already read, try:

```
std::cout << "Input a number: ";
int i = funkcija(std::cin);
std::cout << i << " ";
```

While this would work it seems strange. Consider separating the input- and output-handling from the calculation to improve your design. Change the function to:

```
int funkcija( int value ) {
   if( value%2 == 0 ) {
       return (value/2);
   }
   else return (value*3)+1;
}
```

and maybe call it like this:

```
std::cout << "Input a number: ";
int i;
if( !( std::cin >> i ) ) throw std::exception();
do {
    i = funkcija( i );
    std::cout << i << " ";
} while( i != 1 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried that and it works, but I have to run the function multiple times in a row, until the result is 1. So I was thinking a do-while loop. Any other ideas?

Comment: This works yes. I am learning from one of the books, and this was the assignment. And in the book they worked with std::istream and said to upgrade the program so it would run the function until the result was 1. So I just assumed I had to do it with istream. Anyway thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

i is of type int not istreeam - you're passing i to the function, therefore its complaining that it's an int and not an istream. You can probably pass in std::cin directly to the function.